# I cannot append a child element to a list

Tags: javascript

I used to be able to append a child to a list dynamical but now for some reason the JavaScript functions stop working. Also the error console does not throw any errors and I have place several alert('') methods in between the code to make sure that the method is actually running. this is what I used to have and it used to work perfectly fine:

```
var o = document.getElementById('searchResults');

var li = document.createElement('li'); //creates a list item tag

//if counter is even then highlight the cell different than an odd one
if ((counter) % 2 == 0) {
    li.setAttribute('class', 'par');
} else {
    li.setAttribute('class', 'non');
}

// I copied the inner html from a row that was displaying. I got rid of the dynamic variables
// just so it is a little easier to understand.
li.innerHTML = "<label class='list3p1'>testing</label><label class='list3p2'>testing2</label><label class='list3p3'>2:23</label>";
o.appendChild(li);
```

this function was working but as I added other tables to index.php this functions stopped working. Moreover I have used this similar method in other pages. Also other methods are working and that is the only function that does not seem to work.

Comment: Do you have multiple elements with `id="searchResults"`?  This is not allowed and could be what is breaking the code when you added extra tables.

Comment: What code did you add? Are you sure `searchResults` exists and is an `ul` or `ol` element? And instead of using `setAttribute`, use DOM property names, as in `li.className = 'par';`.

Comment: you have counter initialized elsewhere right?

Comment: worked fine for me http://jsfiddle.net/v7Dv4/    i guess problem is the HTML you have set up initially?

Comment: I found the problem but it still does not make seance to me. That table had a class called invisible and what that class did was that it hided the whole table and whenever I wanted to use the table I change the class property to the visible one. Maybe javascript adds items to the table with the invisible class even though that table has a different class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the visibility. It took me a long time to find. I had the id of the table repeated and the visibility of the other table was hidden therefore I was adding items to a hidden table. sorry for the fool question.